# can not connect to mongo db using the provided credentials in docker-compose file

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: shopdata
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongoData:/data/db


volumes:
  mongoData:
    driver: local
```

Whenever I try to connect to the database using : `mongo -u root -p root`, it says authentication failed. I provided the username and password provided in the docker-compose file.

```
root@5da5f04acd42:/# mongosh "mongodb://172.20.0.2:27017" --username root --authenticationDatabase shopdata
Enter password: ****
Current Mongosh Log ID: 63312c3decdb99f84e6039e4
Connecting to:      mongodb://<credentials>@172.20.0.2:27017/?directConnection=true&authSource=shopdata&appName=mongosh+1.5.0
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

Is there anything I am missing? I just need to connect using the default username and password passed in the docker-compose.

Comment: That's not a Dockerfile, that's a Docker Compose config file. You should be running `docker compose run mongo_db bash`

Comment: @Phil yeah. That's a docker-compose file. I mistyped it

Answer (score 1):

To connect using mongosh, you need to specify authenticationDatabase ( admin for username/password, $external for x509 auth). You will be prompt for password.

```
mongosh "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" --username root --authenticationDatabase admin
```

> To connect to a MongoDB instance requires authentication, use the --username and --authenticationDatabase command-line options. mongosh prompts you for a password, which it masks as you type. - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/connect/

Comment: it still says auth failed. I have update the question with the error

Comment: your authdatabase should be *admin*, not shopdata